# Proving commutativity of addition in Agda

Tags: agda

I'm trying to prove that addition is commutative in Agda, and I can't get it to work.  Here is the relevant code, with the two troublesome goals at the bottom:

```
cong : ∀{A B : Set} (f : A → B) {x y : A} (eq : x ≡ y) → f x ≡ f y
cong f refl = refl

plus-assoc : ∀ x {y z} → (x + y) + z ≡ x + (y + z)
plus-assoc zero = refl
plus-assoc (suc x) = cong suc (plus-assoc x)

plus-zero : ∀ x → x + zero ≡ x
plus-zero zero = refl
plus-zero (suc x) rewrite plus-zero x = refl

plus-suc : ∀ x {y} → x + suc y ≡ suc (x + y)
plus-suc zero = refl
plus-suc (suc x) = cong suc (plus-suc x)

plus-comm : ∀ x {y} → x + y ≡ y + x
plus-comm zero = { }0
plus-comm (suc x) = { }1
```

The goal Agda finds is

```
Goal: .y ≡ .y + zero
```

That obviously looks a lot like plus-zero, but if I don't know how to do a rewrite with .y.

The second goal is

```
Goal: suc (x + .y) ≡ .y + suc x
——————————————————————————————————————————
.y : Nat
x  : Nat
```

If I try a rewrite with plus-suc like so:

```
plus-comm (suc x) rewrite plus-suc x = { }1
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot rewrite by equation of type {y : Nat} →
                               x + suc y ≡ suc (x + y)
when checking that the clause
plus-comm (suc x) rewrite plus-suc x = ? has type
(x : Nat) {y : Nat} → x + y ≡ y + x
```

I can't really make sense of this error.  Any clues?  I could rewrite the whole thing without implicit variables, since that seems to be making things much harder, but I was given the code as is and so I'd like to keep it like it is, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the proof functions with `y` as an implicit argument, but you need and can use it in the definition.

```
pcomm : ∀ x {y} → x + y ≡ y + x
pcomm zero {y} = {!!}
pcomm (suc x) {y} = {!!}
```

You can also supply implicit arguments when calling a function, e.g., `pcomm x {y}`. The function is missing a key argument in order to complete the rewrite.

Tip: If a function has many implicit arguments and you only care about providing a specific one, you can do the following.

```
-- f {C = X}
f : ∀ {A B C : Set} → Set
f {C = C} = C
```